# How do I split these String Arraylist [{ } , {}, { }...] to strings or Integer?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, data-conversion

I have,

```
[{"GroupPosition":0,"ChildPosition":0},{"GroupPosition":0,"ChildPosition":1},{"GroupPosition":1,"ChildPosition":0}]
```

How do I split them into:
GroupPosition:

```
[0,0,1] or {0,0,1}
```

ChildPosition:

```
[0,0,0] or {0,0,0}
```

Comment: [JSON Parser](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)?

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra, thanks for edited my topic which helped me completed my goal.  Thanks and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is in json format. Consider my code is sample.

```
private static ArrayList<String> array_1 = new ArrayList<String>();;
String json = [{"GroupPosition":0,"ChildPosition":0},{"GroupPosition":0,"ChildPosition":1},{"GroupPosition":1,"ChildPosition":0}];
JSONArray leagues = new JSONArray(json);
for (int i = 0; i < leagues.length(); i++) {
JSONObject obj = leagues.getJSONObject(i);
array_1.add(obj.getString("GroupPosition"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Amsheer.  It's very close to what I wanted.  You are truly one of the greatest people.  OUCH, I didn't know there was a topic like this already since I am still new to Android and didn't know what it was called... PARSE got it. -7 to my account WOW

Comment: negative positive vote doesn't matter. When you ask question here just explain what is your problem. what are all the things you tried. That will helps you.

Comment: For developing android application 90% of people use json . But most of the people doesn't understand your question. Keep try. Good luck